# Is it possible to run Jest Snapshot Test with React v0.14.5?

Tags: reactjs, npm, jestjs

Im trying to run a simple jest snapshot test, but to use that, is necessary to have 'react-test-renderer'. But when I try to install the oldest available version of this package (v1.1.0), it still needs that peer dependecy: react-dom@^15.4.2.

Is it possible to run snapshots test on jest witht React v0.14.5?

```
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

test('Link renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
    <Link page="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</Link>
  ).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```